# Maximum value of $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Let $x,y,z,v,w$ be real numbers and
>   $$x+y+z+v+w=8,\qquad x^2+y^2+z^2+v^2+w^2=16.$$
>   Find the maximun value of $x$?

I've solved this question by using the average of the numbers and got $x\leq 16/5$.

Does anyone has another way؟

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(y^2+z^2+v^2+w^2)(1+1+1+1)\ge (y+z+v+w)^2$$